# Add 1 to current year in expression

Tags: vba, date, expression, ssrs-2008, iif

I would like to learn how a year can be added to the current year in ELSE part of the following expression:

```
=IIF(Today() >= cDate("10/01/" + cStr(year(Today()))) AND Today() <= cDate("10/02/" + cStr(year(Today()))),
    cDate("11/01/" + cStr(year(FORMAT(Cdate(today), "MM-dd-yyyy")))),
        cDate("11/01/" + cStr(year(FORMAT(Cdate(today), "MM-dd-yyyy")))))
```

I tried to do this:

```
=IIF(Today() >= cDate("10/01/" + cStr(year(Today()))) AND Today() <= cDate("10/02/" + cStr(year(Today()))),
    cDate("11/01/" + cStr(year(FORMAT(Cdate(today), "MM-dd-yyyy")))),
        cDate("11/01/" + cStr(year(FORMAT(Cdate(today), "MM-dd-yyyy") + 1))))
```

But the report does not accept it as valid syntax.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
DateAdd("yyyy", 1, "10/1/2018")
```

If you want you can formate the date

```
DateAdd("yyyy", 1, Format("10/1/2018", "MM/dd/yyyy"))
```

And you can format the result too!

```
Format(DateAdd("yyyy", 1, Format("10/1/2018", "MM/dd/yyyy")), "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

check it here
https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dateadd.php

and here
https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/format_date.php

Comment: Why on earth would you format a date and pass it to something expecting a date parameter?

Comment: Because your date (string) could be in any format. If you dont need to format your date, just use DateAdd!

Comment: "10/01/2018" can be 10 of jan or 1 oct, depending on format

Comment: @JorgeRibeiro no. `#10/1/2018#` is a *date literal*, i.e. a `Date` value. So you're taking a `Date`, turning it into a `String`, then passing that to `DateAdd` (which then needs to implicitly convert it back to a `Date`), ..and then turning the resulting `Date` into a `String`. Madness.

Comment: Every time you convert between a string and a date, you introduce the possibility that it will be misrepresented.  The reason date data types ***exist*** is to provide a canonical way to represent them that avoids regional differences in how they are displayed.

Comment: Ok right i will edit the code. instead of use `#date#` i will use `"date"`. The point is that dateadd will solve the problem

Comment: By the way, i just want to help! Thanks Comintern to clarify